# Excel changing integer value

Tags: excel

I'm trying to copy&paste this number:

```
1025649944456874
```

from a text editor to excel. The values changes to this:

```
1025649944456870
```

what's going on ?

Microsoft office professional Plus 2010 - Excel version 14.0.7165.5000 (32 bit).
OS: Win7

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is looking at the number in number format, and auto-formats to scientific format. This will cause excel to auto trim the number. If you format the cell as text and then paste in, it will keep the entire string correctly.

Comment: it worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the link below the number precision maximum limit in Excel is 15 digits:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

If you are not going to make any calculations on the number, you might just want to format it as text to retain all digits.

Answer (score 0):

After copying from your text editor:

- click in the Formula Bar
- touch the single quote key
- touch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>
- touch the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key

This will get all the digits entered as Text.